# Which things i can put in service in angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have read many articles but still could not find how to put stuff in services.

Currently this is my Service

```
angular
  .module('users')
  .factory('objectiveService', objectiveService);

objectiveService.$inject = ['$http', 'Restangular'];

function objectiveService($http, Restangular) {
  return {
    getObjectives: getObjectives,
    getSingleObjective: getSingleObjective
  };

  function getObjectives(pid) {
    var pr = Restangular
      .all('api')
      .all('users')
      .one('subjects', pid)
      .all('objectives');

    return pr;
  }

  function getSingleObjective(oid) {
    var pr = Restangular
      .all('api')
      .all('users')
      .one('objectives', oid);

    return pr

  }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
var _vm = this;
this.objPromise = objectiveService.getObjectives(44);

function getData() {
  var promise = _vm.objPromise;

  promise
    .getList(filters)
    .then(function(result) {
      $scope.gridData = result;
    });
}

function remove(id) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this!')) {
    objectiveService.getSingleObjective(id).remove().then(function() {
      $scope.getData();
    });

  }
}

// initial call   
$scope.getData();
```

In this code i basically see no use to define service because I still has to use `then()` in the controller to assign data to Grid.

Also I can't use `then()` in service because there I don't have $scope to update the data.

People say to do all stuff in service but I am not able to figure out how.

Ideally I want to put all functions like `remove(object_id)` in service

IS it possible that I can just do `objectiveService.remove(id)` in controller.

But then I have to call `$scope.getData()` after deleting which I can't do in service

Comment: What is your problem with calling `.then` in the controller? This is normal. The controller is clearly dealing with just assigning data to the ViewModel (inside `.then`, in this case), and the service is dealing with the backend. Clear separation of concerns

Comment: @NewDev . The problem is with error function of then. Because i always display erros in the top section and code is same. but i have to repeat that in all `then()` functions . Is there any way my apromises use same error function

Comment: sure, create a single function, say `errorHandler`, and just pass a reference to it: `getObjectives().catch(errorHandler)`

Comment: @NewDev is it possible to define that function somewhere so that it gets applies to all promises so that i don't need to explicitly write that line. IN jquery there was `ajaxSetup` which was applied to all ajax request

Comment: I guess you could allow to register an error handler with your service, which the controller would call in the beginning, and then have you service invoke it in its own `.catch`. And you'd have to support registering multiple handlers for different controllers that may use the same service at the same time. But this is completely unnecessary and over-complicates something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to use services is not to avoid the use of `.then`. In your controller you would use `.then` like so:

```
objectiveService.getObjectives(filters)
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.gridData = result;
    });
```

`.then` is required as the call to get data occurs asynchronously.

Some reasons taken from [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#data-services):

- The controller's responsibility is for the presentation and gathering of information for the view. It should not care how it gets the data, just that it knows who to ask for it.
- This makes it easier to test (mock or real) the data calls when testing a controller that uses a data service.
- Data service implementation may have very specific code to handle the data repository. This may include headers, how to talk to the data, or other services such as $http. Separating the logic into a data service encapsulates this logic in a single place hiding the implementation from the outside consumers (perhaps a controller), also making it easier to change the implementation.

If you put the code in the controller it also means it's not reusable. You can't use it in more than one controller or you can't you it in another service.